# superimpose images of different dimensions in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I was wondering how to superimpose two images (source and target) of different resolution and dimensions for display. Actually, I wanted to rotate and translate those images in order to align them or technically speaking register two images.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
img_source = np.random.randint(50, size=(150,250)) # distance between two pixels is 1 mm 
img_target = np.random.randint(900, size=(750,900)) # distance between two pixels is 0.005 mm

# i do not know how to superimpose them 
# may be import CV2
img_reg = cv2.addWeighted(img_source,0.8,img_target,0.3,0)
cv2.imshow('reg', img_reg)

# rotate target img if its not well aligned with source image
rotate_target = ndimage.rotate(img_target, 1, reshape=False)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What kind of images? Do you know any corresponding points between the images?

Comment: Usually I plot profile through the images and align them without any specific points. If you think that would be easy if there are any corresponding points, I could as well create on them.

Comment: You could use [`ndimage.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html) to scale one image to the same resolution as the other image.

Comment: with ndimage, it looks like its modifying the results. I don't want to change the data.